# Access IO ports via windows driver from Visual C#

Tags: c#, sys

I have with me a Windows driver (.sys) format

I need to access this driver from Visual C#.
When I try to add this driver as a reference from Visual C#, I get the below error "Make sure this is a valid assembly or COM component"

***Edits***
The driver is to control WDT through IO ports and has IOCTL calls. How can I make use of the driver and set/reset watchdog using a VC# application?

---

I am new to VC# and would like you to provide ideas, that I can explore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the driver?   As the message says, you can only add a reference to a valid .NET assembly or a COM component, which the driver is not.

Comment: @Tim The driver is to control WDT through IO ports and has IOCTL calls. How can I make use of the driver and set/reset watchdog using a VC# application?

Comment: It's really unclear what accessing a driver from C# is meant to be. Also, does the [tag:sys] tag have *any* relevance here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drivers in Windows are kernel-mode components, they are loaded by the operating system directly into kernel space (generally-speaking; certain drivers live in userland and can also live in virtual memory too, but those are exceptions). Your driver will have been (or rather: should be) installed by an installation program. Contact the vendor for installation instructions if you were provided with just a binary. Each driver has its own special installation steps so I cannot tell you how to install it.

For a userland process (i.e. your .NET application) you use the Win32 API's `DeviceIOControl` function to send messages to a driver, these messages can include callback addresses which enables a driver to communicate back with the userland process.

A userland program will do this:

1. Call `CreateFile` to create a file-descriptor which represents the device

   - Ignore the fact it's called "File", this is one of the cases where Windows resembles Unix's "everything is a file"-philosophy.
   - Devices are typically under the namespace `\\.\${deviceName}` which compares with Unix's `/dev/${id}` namespace, for example. Note that each backslash needs to be escaped, so `\\.\Foo` becomes `"\\\\.\\Foo"` in C/C++.
   - File-descriptors in Windows are abstractions that represent many kinds of objects, you can see a listing of objects using the WinObj utility: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/winobj.aspx
2. Call `DeviceIoControl` (passing in the file-descriptor from step 1).

   - The other parameters in the `DeviceIoControl` are defined by the driver or the driver's "device class" - not knowing more about your driver I cannot provide further assistance.
3. Don't forget to call `CloseHandle` afterwards.

   - Be sure to call it in exceptional circumstances too (e.g. in a `finally` block in C# or wrap all access in an `IDisposable` implementation). As you're dealing with a third-party driver of unknown provenance I don't know how reliably it will handle an unpredictable userland process. Certainly this is how userland programs can crash an entire system: by triggering bugs in kernel-mode drivers via `DeviceIoControl`.

Depending on the device, your userland program may need to run as an elevated process (with administrative rights) in order for `DeviceIoControl` calls to succeed.

This page on MSDN details how you can use `DeviceIoControl` to communicate with a driver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147(v=vs.85).aspx however specific argument values will need to be be gleaned from your driver's documentation.